# Maximum area of triangle, tangent

Tags: maxima-minima

In the following problem:

Consider the set of all triangles whose sides are the x and y axes and tangents to the curve e^{-4 x}, x>0. Calculate the maximum area such a triangle can have.

I have tried to solve it, but the answer is apparently wrong, what have I missed?

y = e⁻⁴ˣ ⟹ dy/dx = -4e⁻⁴ˣ = -1 ⟹

x = (1/2)*ln(0.25) = 0.3465 & y = 0.2501

plug into y = -x+c to find c = 0.5966 both x & y intercept.

area triangle is (0.5966)²/2 = 0.178 units² Answer

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ?? what can I find there?

Comment: How to format your post